# What Python plugin should I use with XAMPP

Tags: python, html, apache, xampp

Hi all this is just a general question if anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

I am creating a website for a college project and i'm using XAMPP to develop the website. I require a Python plugin as I am trying to create an area where the user can type in a python script and the response will be mirrored in an adjacent iframe.

I was going to use mod_python as the plugin but from research into this i have found that this is now dead and will eventually not be supported.

Has anyone got any advice into what I should use because i can not find any relevant information online.

Many thanks Andy Rose

Comment: Check out [`mod_wsgi`](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've already commented, but I'll add a little historical context.

[`mod_python`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mod_python) used to be the defacto standard, at least unofficially, but back in 2003, the Python web-sig's proposal for a formal standard for a Python web interface was published as [PEP333](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/), more commonly known as the Python [Web Server Gateway Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface), or WSGI.

Since then, [`mod_wsgi`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mod_wsgi) was created to support the new standard, although `mod_python` can also be used with the appropriate wrappers.

As for which is 'better', that's a subjective question, but `mod_wsgi` seems to be preferred by the majority of the Python community. For example, [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) dropped support for `mod_python` in 2011.